# Git trying to push non existent repository

Tags: reactjs, git

I installed a new react app in Visual Studio Code and tried to push it to my git repository from local.
After "git add -A", "git commit -m "Initial commit" and "git push --set-upstream origin master" I get an error that it can't be pushed.

> fatal: 'https//github.com/UserName/SomeOldProject' does not appear to
> be a git repository

This "SomeOldProject" doesn't exist for a while now because I deleted it a few months ago from local and my git repo. I don't know where this comes from. I already deleted "create-react-app" and re-installed it but nothing changed.

I also had the problem that some old and deleted repositories showed up on local after I installed "create-react-app". Still don't know where this comes from, because I deleted most of them a long time ago.

Is there anything I can do here to clear some cache or something else so it won't track all the old files?

Comment: the local project references to `https//github.com/UserName/SomeOldProject` but the GitHub repository has been deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure is a remote configured in this repository?

Try this command:

```
git remote -v
```

This command should list your configured repositories, and check if exists a repository configured or if it's right.

If you need to add a new repository to your project, try this command:

```
git remote add origin <git_url>
```

This command add a new git repository using orgin (default name) as alias.

Look this tutorial to understand more about remotes: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/syncing